# Python: How to write data in file in specific format?

Tags: python, string-formatting

i have an array called MAC1_Val:

> > > MAC1_Val
> > >       array([  1.00000000e+00,  -1.00000000e+01,  -2.06306600e+02,
> > >                2.22635749e+02,   1.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+01,
> > >                1.00000000e+01,  -2.06306600e+02,   2.22635749e+02,
> > >                0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
> > >                0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
> > >                0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
> > >                0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
> > >                0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,
> > >                0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,
> > >               -1.08892735e+01,   1.88607749e+01,   1.03153300e+01,
> > >               -1.78666757e+01,   3.33333333e-07,  -3.33333333e-07,
> > >               -4.21637021e-05,   4.21637021e-05,   9.98844400e-01,
> > >               -1.73973001e-03,   1.20938900e-03,   1.87742948e-03,
> > >               -3.33333333e-03,   6.66666667e-03,  -3.33333333e-03,
> > >               -2.64911064e-01,  -2.60959501e+01,   2.81614422e+01,
> > >                3.33333333e-03,  -6.66666667e-03,   3.33333333e-03,
> > >                0.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00])

and i want to write in file (.txt) values in specific format like this:

```
1.000000e+00
-1.000000e+01 
-2.063066e+02
2.226357e+02
1.000000e+00   
1.000000e+01 .......
```

note that are 6 digits behind floating point

any suggestions how to do this?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**printf** standard is your friend:

```
for i in MAC1_Val:
    print "%.6e" % i

1.000000e+00
-1.000000e+01
-2.063066e+02
2.226357e+02
1.000000e+00
1.000000e+01
1.000000e+01
```

Comment: Or just `"%.6e" % i`.  I don't think that the `1` in `"%1.6e"` means what you think it means...

Answer (score 1):

Use [string interpolation](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) to format the number.

```
'%.3f' % (1.23456,)
```

Comment: And then just write it (plus a newline) using the vanilla `write` method of the file object.

Comment: the 'e' format is for esponential, f for float, so it's better to use "%1.6e".

Comment: >>> '%.3f' % (1467.23456,)
'1467.235'
and i need 1.467+e03

Comment: @Enrico Carlesso,@Tadeusz A. Kadłubowski :thanks a lot guys!!!!that's exactly what i need!!!!!!